# Ошибка "$ is not defined" в FireFox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

Здравствуйте всем!

Появилась очень странная проблема. IE, Opera всегда нормально грузят страницу, грузит её нормально и Firefox, но, что удивительно - не всегда. Я до сих пор не могу однозначно понять, когда именно происходит сбой и для того, чтобы смоделировать ситуацию заново вынужден просто ждать, когда это случится. Явление носит, как вы поняли, непостоянный характер.
Иногда Firefox при нажатии на F5 подгружает скрипты заново то ли не полностью, то ли совсем не подгружает (хотя в firebug в html-мониторе всё отображает всегда как подгруженное) и выдает ошибку $ is not defined для файлов, которые идут следом за подгружаемым jquery-файлом и используют jQuery.

В хроме данная ошибка ведет себя по-другому. Если Firefox всегда при первой загрузке страницы грузит всё правильно, а уже потом при нажатии f5 может сбойнуть (не факт, но может), то хром напротив, иногда дает сбой при первой загрузке, а при нажатии f5 всегда всё возвращается на свои места. Явление так же носит непостоянный характер и смоделировать сразу же не получается.

Есть подозрение, что проблема вовсе не на стороне клиента, а что-то с настройками сервера(Apache 2). Пробовал менять время исполнения скрипта (увеличил с 30 до 120 секунд, мало ли) - не помогло.

Есть ли у кого-нибудь какие-то идеи? Проблема уж очень странная.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <!--meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no" /-->

    <title>
        mytitle
    </title>
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleN.css"/>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/LAB.src.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
                $LAB
                .script('/js/jquery-1.7.min.js').wait()
                .script('/js/javascript1.js').wait()
                .script('/js/javascript2.js').wait()
                .script('/js/javascriptN.js').wait()
</script>
```

вот это head

Comment: Где Вы берёте jQuery? Со своего хостинга или с CDN?

Comment: Пожалуйста, вставьте в сообщение код области <head></head>. Поведение, похожее на асинхронное подключение js-файлов.

Comment: да, извините, что сразу не написал. конечно, у себя. даже уже 777 выставил на эти папки. все равно не помогло.

Comment: Обратите внимание на мой комментарий к вопросу.

Comment: сначала подключал по обычному в тегах <script>, затем перешел на использование LAB.js. Однако, насколько я её понимаю, там функции wait() обеспечивают задержку до полной загрузки скрипта и только потом начинают грузить следующий. Но тем не менее... тоже почему-то фейлит.

Comment: Вероятно, вы забыли занести inline-скрипты в $LAB.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под inline скриптами? Я все скрипты, которые у меня были, перенес в LAB за исключением подключения самого LAB.js.

Comment: inline-скрипты — это скрипты в самом коде документа между тегами <script />

Comment: интересную кажется вещь я понял. я сделал рекурсивную загрузку. грубо говоря, если не загрузился jquery, то вызвать еще раз функцию загрузки заново, а старую прервать и так до тех пор, пока не загрузит. хром выдал: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Т.е. он просто не желает подключать скрипт. Уж хоть 1 раз из 1000 рекурсивных вызовов должен был пройти (даже если асинхронно) чисто по вероятности. Но нет. Что-то мешает.

Comment: Покажите ваш HEAD (или ссылку на страницу) — разберемся :)

Comment: head привел. ничего необычного, кроме, пожалуй, попытки очищать кэш, вроде нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в кэше браузера. В общем-то решить удалось. Если бы я мог отвечать на свои вопросы, то, конечно, расписал бы подробно решение. А так ограничусь тем, что скажу: нужно было запретить кэширование в html и сделать скрипты не кэшируемыми вовсе. Грузится всё достаточно быстро даже без кэширования.
Видимо, какая-то проблема в самом браузере.

Спасибо за предоставленую возможность отвечать!

Значит так. Основная суть проблемы крылась в самом браузере. В конечном счете, ведь в IE10 и Opera всё работало без единого сбоя (Даже в IE! Хочу отметить:) ). Потом я стал замечать, что не только мой сайт, но и популярные порталы типа VK.COM и YOUTUBE.COM ведут себя похожим образом (особенно в хроме). Это мне и показалось совсем странным.

Тем не менее, временно решил проблему следующим образом:
в head

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

А сами скрипты подключаю либо с PHP-вставкой:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="LAB.src.js?v=<?php echo rand(); ?>"></script>
```

Либо, если через LAB.js, то так:

```
$LAB.script('/js/jquery.tools.min.js?v=' + Math.random()).wait()
```

Таким образом я "обманываю" свой браузер и не даю ему кэшировать скрипты. Ошибки прекратились как в хроме, так и в Firefox. Хотя и понятно, что у меня что-то с браузером, но может и кому-то другому поможет для очистки кэша средствами PHP или JS.

UPD1: Проблема браузера заключалась в антивирусе Norton. После его удаления глюки с кэшем вроде прекратились

Comment: @luxor, Ваш комментарий преобразован в ответ. Вы также можете отредактировать ваш ответ, расписав подробно решение.

Comment: Еще раз спасибо!